# Integrating react-native Into iPhone Voicemail Functionality

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

A Stack Overflow Search... turned up very little for my subject.  However, I did read "Integrating react-native into existing App" and "Integration with Existing Apps", from the React Native Docs, and don't think either applies.  I also ran across something called "CallKit" in the Apple Developer Documentation, but not sure if it applies either.  I want to code an App that accesses and extends the functionality of the iPhone Voicemail data.  I need to access and display "Blocked Messages" for my App.

I don't see an API for that anywhere, unless I'm overlooking something, and I'm a little confused as to what tools are required.  I have XCode installed, but use another IDE with 'create-react-native-app ' to develop with. Can someone point me in the right direction of research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no easy way of doing this. The iOS SDK **does not provide** a way to access Voicemails.

Using **CallKit** an app can [add a contact to the list of blocked contacts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcalldirectoryextensioncontext/1779571-addblockingentry), but not access Voicemails or similar.